# vue transition mode="out-in" returns a ref element as undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

So this is an issue when `mode="out-in"` is applied as in `<transition mode="out-in">` a `ref`'d element returned undefined during the `updated` lifecycle. However, without the `mode="out-in"` it works as expected.

How can I resolve this?

https://codesandbox.io/s/mjy8jr4148

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it by using using a transition hook, specifically `after-enter`

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#JavaScript-Hooks